# What to put in gitignore when using bii with Travis

Tags: c++, travis-ci, biicode

I'm experimenting with setting up CI with Travis and bii. There is [documentation available on the biicode website](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/reference/configuration_files/ignore.html) including an example `ignore.bii` file, which relates to publishing blocks.

Can anyone provide an example of what bii specific files and folders I should be ignoring in my `.gitignore` in a continuous integration setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the biicode project layout defined at init.
If you use the "simple" layout ($ bii init -L), then you should gitignore:

```
bii/
bin/
```

bii contains cmake, build, deps subfolders, all of them can be ignored
bin contains the output binaries, typically ignored too

If using the normal layout, actually the repo should be in project/blocks/username/blockname and the biicode auxiliary files would be in a parent folder, nothing to ignore.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example, [Eric Niebler's Meta library](https://github.com/ericniebler/meta/blob/master/.gitignore):

```
# BiiCode
bii/
```